# Convert an Oracle query to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL query in Oracle and I want to convert it into a SQL Server 2017 query

```
SELECT     
    BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$CWAR, BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$LOCA, 
    BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$ITEM, BAANDB.TTIITM001300.T$DSCA, 
    BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$CLOT, BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$STUN, 
    BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$STKS, BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$CREA, 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(BAANDB.TTIITM001300.T$CITG)) AS T$CITG, 
    BAANDB.TTCMCS023300.T$DSCA AS CITG_DSCA, BAANDB.TTIITM001300.T$COPR, 
    BAANDB.TTIITM001300.T$COPR * BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$STKS AS VALO, 
    BAANDB.TTCMCS003300.T$DSCA AS CWAR_DSCA, 
    BAANDB.TCSILC503300.T$ACOD, BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$TRAN, 
    TO_CHAR(BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$CREA) AS EXPR1, 
    BAANDB.TTCCOM001300.T$DIVI
FROM
    BAANDB.TTDILC101300, BAANDB.TTIITM001300, BAANDB.TTCMCS023300, 
    BAANDB.TTCMCS003300, BAANDB.TTDINV001300, 
    BAANDB.TTCCOM001300, BAANDB.TTDLTC001300, BAANDB.TCSILC503300
WHERE     
    BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$ITEM = BAANDB.TTIITM001300.T$ITEM 
    AND BAANDB.TTIITM001300.T$CITG = BAANDB.TTCMCS023300.T$CITG 
    AND BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$CWAR = BAANDB.TTCMCS003300.T$CWAR 
    AND BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$CWAR = BAANDB.TTDINV001300.T$CWAR 
    AND BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$ITEM = BAANDB.TTDINV001300.T$ITEM 
    AND BAANDB.TTCMCS003300.T$EMNO = BAANDB.TTCCOM001300.T$EMNO (+) 
    AND BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$ITEM = BAANDB.TTDLTC001300.T$ITEM (+) 
    AND BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$CWAR = BAANDB.TCSILC503300.T$CWAR (+) 
    AND (BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$CLOT = BAANDB.TTDLTC001300.T$CLOT (+)) 
    AND (BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$CWAR IN (:cwar)) 
    AND (BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$ITEM LIKE '%' || :item || '%')
ORDER BY 
    BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$CWAR, BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$LOCA, 
    BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$ITEM, BAANDB.TTDILC101300.T$CLOT
```

Comment: Hey there.  I think you may want to give it an attempt yourself and then, if you get stuck, discuss where you're getting stuck.  I can tell you right now though you'll want to convert those where statements and comma'd from statement in to proper join statements.

Comment: I did the conversion but I'm stuck in the part "BAANDB.TTCCOM001300.T$EMNO (+)"

Comment: I'm stuck in converting (+)

Comment: the (+) is for outer join  ..  you can change using explicit join syntax and left join

Comment: Time to start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for more than 25 years. Also, some aliases and formatting would turn that wall of text into something legible and suportable.

Comment: If it's using those janky old-style joins, it was a bad query in Oracle, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that would look close like this.

Using the modern JOIN syntax, and with aliases.

```
SELECT
ttdilc.T$CWAR, 
ttdilc.T$LOCA, 
ttdilc.T$ITEM, 
ttiitm.T$DSCA, 
ttdilc.T$CLOT, 
ttdilc.T$STUN,
ttdilc.T$STKS, 
ttdilc.T$CREA,
LTRIM(RTRIM(ttiitm.T$CITG)) AS T$CITG, 
ttcmcs033.T$DSCA AS CITG_DSCA, 
ttiitm.T$COPR, 
ttiitm.T$COPR * ttdilc.T$STKS AS VALO, 
ttcmcs033.T$DSCA AS CWAR_DSCA, 
tcsilc.T$ACOD, 
ttdilc.T$TRAN, 
CAST(ttdilc.T$CREA AS VARCHAR(30)) AS EXPR1, 
ttccom.T$DIVI
FROM BAANDB.TTDILC101300 AS ttdilc
JOIN BAANDB.TTIITM001300 AS ttiitm
  ON ttdilc.T$ITEM = ttiitm.T$ITEM 
JOIN BAANDB.TTCMCS023300 AS ttcmcs233
  ON ttiitm.T$CITG = ttcmcs233.T$CITG 
JOIN BAANDB.TTCMCS003300 AS ttcmcs033
  ON ttdilc.T$CWAR = ttcmcs033.T$CWAR 
JOIN BAANDB.TTDINV001300 AS ttdinv
  ON ttdilc.T$CWAR = ttdinv.T$CWAR 
AND ttdilc.T$ITEM = ttdinv.T$ITEM 
LEFT JOIN BAANDB.TTCCOM001300 AS ttccom
  ON ttcmcs033.T$EMNO = ttccom.T$EMNO
LEFT JOIN BAANDB.TTDLTC001300 AS ttdltc
  ON ttdilc.T$ITEM = ttdltc.T$ITEM
 AND ttdilc.T$CLOT = ttdltc.T$CLOT
LEFT JOIN BAANDB.TCSILC503300 AS tcsilc
  ON ttdilc.T$CWAR = tcsilc.T$CWAR
WHERE ttdilc.T$CWAR = @cwar
  AND ttdilc.T$ITEM LIKE concat('%', @item, '%')
ORDER BY 
ttdilc.T$CWAR, 
ttdilc.T$LOCA, 
ttdilc.T$ITEM, 
ttdilc.T$CLOT
```

Comment: Side-note. Besides the variables and the `CONCAT`, this query might also work on the Oracle DB.